# udev add hidraw and immediately remove

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev

I have problems in using self-made hid device on my Ubuntu 17.10.
It works fine on Windows and works fine on another machine with Kubuntu 18.04.

I already removed all my udev rules, restarted udev, reboot PC, but nothing changes.

Every time I connect the device it is added and immediately removed.

Here is `udevadm monitor` output:

```
KERNEL[6204.330291] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4 (usb)
KERNEL[6204.332824] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6204.337649] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006 (hid)
KERNEL[6204.337676] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
KERNEL[6204.337781] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[6204.337902] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [6204.339176] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [6204.342657] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4 (usb)
KERNEL[6204.343301] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[6204.343321] remove   /usbmisc (class)
KERNEL[6204.343441] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
KERNEL[6204.343467] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006 (hid)
UDEV  [6204.344076] remove   /usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [6204.349535] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6204.353769] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006 (hid)
UDEV  [6204.353793] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [6204.353805] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [6204.353819] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [6204.354254] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [6204.355106] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006 (hid)
KERNEL[6204.921022] add      /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
KERNEL[6204.921041] remove   /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
UDEV  [6204.922874] add      /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
UDEV  [6204.923290] remove   /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
KERNEL[6209.296515] add      /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
UDEV  [6209.298376] add      /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
KERNEL[6209.348220] remove   /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
UDEV  [6209.349800] remove   /devices/parport0/ppdev0.0 (parport)
```

The most strange for me this 2 lines:

```
UDEV  [6204.353819] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [6204.354254] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4/5-1.4:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
```

In result, there are neither `hidraw3` no `hiddev0` files in /dev

Please suggest something I can try to see the reason for this behavior.

Thank you.

**Update** Here is dmesg output:

```
[ 1897.305402] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 1897.446811] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
[ 1897.446820] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1897.446825] usb 3-6: Product: Smart Display
[ 1897.446829] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: QS
[ 1897.446832] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 00000000001A
[ 1897.448254] hid-generic 0003:0483:5750.0008: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.01 Device [QS Smart Display] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
```

Comment: Please edit question with output of `dmesg` after you plug in the device, to see if there's any errors or reasons for the remove event.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu Xenial when I plugged my barcode scanner in.

I checked /var/log/syslog and also the output of lsof to figure out that I was having this bug from fwupd:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1717009

I stopped fwupd and I was able to scan barcodes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But thats was not my case. What helped me indeed is ubuntu upgrade to 18.04